# 2 loops, is_home won't work, count is off

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, query-posts

Alright, I've made a bunch of themes over the years, and I've written a lot of queries. And I just realized that I apparently have no clue how to get multiple queries to behave. So, here is the loops from my index.php:

```
        <?php do_action( 'voodoo_pre_loop' ); ?>

        <?php if( is_home() ) : ?>

            <?php $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
            );
            $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) : ?>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $more_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 9,
                'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
                'paged' => $paged
            );
            query_posts( $more_args ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php voodoo_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

                <?php $format = get_post_format();
                if ( false === $format )
                    $format = 'standard';
                    get_template_part( 'content', $format ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php voodoo_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php voodoo_else(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

So, what I expected to have happen, was to have a loop. It would just grab one post. If there was a sticky, we'd grab it. If not, then the most recent post. That would always farm out to content-featured for the display. This loop seems to work. I get a stick / or not if there aren't any. And content-featured is called. This is all in the is_home, because I only want it to happen on the home/ front page.

Still in is_home is a widget area. That ain't complicated.

Next up, a second loop. My logic, the query was still inside the is_home. On the front page, I wanted 9 posts, never any stickies, no duplicates of that first post. On subsequent pages, I figured I didn't need that query. I just want all the other pages to show my standard 10 posts. No featured thing, no sidebar, etc.

So where this seems to get me, is that first post, the widget, and a mess.

That second area, I only ever get 7 posts. On subsequent pages, I still get that first featured loop which I don't want. And I only get 8 posts. I have read all over the internet, and I'm obviously not grasping something.

Any ideas:
Why is_home or is_front_page won't work here?
Why I can't get my numbers right? (1+9 posts is home, 10 posts remaining pages)

I'd love a little help here so I can understand this all a bit better. Thanks!

Comment: 'On subsequent pages' - does this refer to paginated pages of the front page? in which case, you might need to use `is_home && !is_paged()` in the conditional.

Comment: Yup paginated pages. I'll try that and report back, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query should be reset with [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after its loop has finished to avoid conflicts with the main query. Glancing over your code, that's the most important flaw I see.

Also, I'd use `$my_query_2 = new WP_Query( $more_args );` for the second one - I don't see why it'd be better to revert back to using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) might be worth a read.

While were at it: It shouldn't affect the functionality of your code at all, but why in the world are there so many php opening and closing tags (i.e. `<?php` and `?>`) ? That might make sense if you have HTML markup in between and dislike echoing, but given that that's not the case, just put `<?php` at the top of the document (or the relevant section) and `?>` at the bottom. It will make for more legible code both for you yourself as well as people helping you.

**EDIT:** Mkay. This works as expected on my dev install:

```
<ul>            
<?php
    $per_page = is_paged() ? 10 : 9;
    $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $offset = empty( $stickies ) ? 1 : 0;
    if( is_home() && !is_paged() ) {
        $per_page = 9;
        $args_first_query = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post__in' => $stickies,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
        );
        $first_query = new WP_Query( $args_first_query );
        if( $first_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($first_query->have_posts()) : $first_query->the_post();
                // replace with your template part:
                echo '<li>Latest Sticky:'.get_the_title().'</li>';
            endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    // your sidebar
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args_main_query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
        'post__not_in' => $stickies,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'offset' => $offset
    );
    query_posts( $args_main_query );
    if( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts()) : the_post();
            $format = get_post_format();
            if ( false === $format )
                $format = 'standard';
            echo '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
        endwhile;
    }
    // pagination, with check for WP-PageNavi plugin
    if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {
        wp_pagenavi();
    } elseif ( get_next_posts_link() || get_previous_posts_link() ) {
        next_posts_link( '&laquo; Older Entries' );
        previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries &raquo;' );
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
```

I'd suggest you check whether the above works on your site as well. If it does, drop your custom stuff in one by one, see whether it fails and if so, when.

This check `if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;` is definitely superfluous, given that the first query only takes stickies and the second one doesn't at all. So you can for sure omit that line and the related one in the 1st query.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The query setup came directly from the codex, it's nearly identical including lack of resetting. I did try reseting the queries earlier. As for the code, I'll clean it up. I pretty much hack things together as I think of them, and then clean everything up later. I'll try out the tips and report back. Also, voodoo_pre_loop does nothing. It's for later use.

Comment: Alright, I used wp_reset_postdata after the first loop. Also tried switching out to a new MY_Query instead of query_posts. None of that made any difference. I've got my conditional working per the suggestion above, but I'm now getting 1+7 posts on the homepage and 9 on the paginated pages. instead of 1+9, and 10. Any more ideas? Thanks so far!

Comment: Here's my train of thought. That second query for 9 posts is inside the conditional still. So I thought it would only execute on is_home. That's why I assumed I would get 1+9 posts. Outside of the homepage, that entire first query shouldf be ignored (it is) and the second query should be ignore too, giving me my default posts count of 10 on paginated pages. Instead, I ask for 9 on fron page and get 7, and I want 10 on other pages, get 9.

Comment: @Rev.Voodoo Mkay. Instead of attempting to debug your code, I quickly rewrote and tested it in my dev environment. Works - see the edit. I couldn't copy yours and test that, cause it's got to much stuff specific to your theme. I suggest you test the above and adapt it back to your customization, if it works for you as well. Should just output a list of post titles. Am getting 10 and 10, as expected.

Comment: I'm getting 10 on the first page, and 9 on subsequent pages (I did verify that my WP settings were at 10 per page). Also, that first loop isn't intended to get only stickies. It grabs a sticky if one exists, otherwise it grabs the latest normal post. This loop is better than what I had for sure, appreciate the effort for real! I really want to nail down ensuring I get exactly the # of posts I query, so I can plan the layout around it.

Comment: @Rev.Voodoo I get your point about the first loop grabbing the latest post if no stickies exist, but that can be solved slicker: replacing the 6th line of my above code (`$per_page = 9;`) by `if( !empty( $stickies ) ) $per_page = 9;` will take care of that (fails if there are sticky posts in the trash). Also since we're redefining the `'posts_per_page'` in the main query anyway, your WP settings don't matter. Could be set to 5, 3 or 0. As for there still being 9 instead of 10 on subsequent pages I have to give up. Sorry. Since the above works on my setup, there ain't no way to further test.

Comment: That's why I had my second query inside the is_home conditional. I was hoping to only have that second query work on the first page, allowing the rest of the pages to revert to the WP option setting. I appreciate the effort, I'll mess with the info you gave me and see what I come up with. I'm on a brand new WP install (3.3), dunno why I'm getting different results than you are.

Comment: @Rev.Voodoo Fixed up the main conditional to include `!empty( $stickies )`. Better performance and cleaner code, but unfortunately won't (shouldn't anyway, who knows what's going on - we don't apparently) be affecting the 9 vs. 10 posts on paginated pages issue. Hope for your sake someone with an idea will come along. Will revisit 2morrow just cause I got curious now...

Comment: OK, I cleared up one problem. We only echoed the title. I'm using the theme test unit. one of the posts doesn't have a title! So I didn't realize it was there. I'm getting the right amount of posts now. My main problem is, if there are no stickies, that first loop doesn't come in to play (is that correct?). I need that first loop to grab the sticky (if it exists) OR the latest post (if there are no stickies), it's going to have it's own output to be displayed differently. Everything else is working spendidly, and thank you!

Comment: @Rev.Voodoo Aight. One last edit, you should be set. Removed the `!empty( $stickies )` from the conditional. If there are no stickies, wp_query ignores `'post__in' => $stickies,`. Added an `offset` parameter to the 2nd query to account for the case of no stickies. Otherwise, 10 & 10 would work, but the 2nd query would repeat the 1st post already displayed by the 1st query. The `$offset` variable gets populated by `1` or `0` respectively, depending on whether there are stickies or not. Once again: Stickies in the trash will break it, just remove the "stickiness" from trashed items and drafts.

Comment: Yup, that'll work! Thanks for helping a guy out man! Tested it a few different ways, nothing broke. Proper loops used, etc. Very much appreciated!